# Trouble removing package from Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, nuget-package

I accidently added a package to my VS2010 MVC 3 project via the 'Manage NuGet Packages' tool in the 'Tools' menu and I would like to remove it, however after some research I can't seem to figure out how to do it.

I have tried opening up the 'Manage NuGet Packages' tool within the solution, but there seems to be no uninstall option so I searched online and found the following [article on installing and uninstalling packages](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/timlee/archive/2010/11/11/using-the-library-package-manager-with-add-on-libraries-in-visual-studio.aspx). It mentions right clicking on the project and choosing the 'Add Package Library Reference' option, but this doesn't exist. I did notice that the example's project is a Website type, where mine isn't as I am using a modified version of the MVC project template.

Anyway, I searched online again and found several mentions of starting VS2010 as an Administrator and then the option for uninstalling should be available in the 'Manage NuGet Packages' tool, however this didn't change anything and no uninstall option appears.

Can anyone suggest what might be the problem and how to remove this package?

Comment: Thanks for the answers so far. I will try them out later when I get to the relevant machine!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a [link](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/start-here/using-the-package-manager-console) to the docs:

Go to the section entitled Removing a Package, you can use the console to uninstall the package you want.

Answer (score 1):

From the Library Package Manager, click the Installed Packages tab, then click Manage on the package you want to remove.  Clear the checkbox for the solution/project you want the package uninstalled from, then click OK.

Or, open up the Package Manager Console and type "uninstall-package YourPackageName".